# Pegar o intervalo de datas separado por semanas do mês atual

Tags: php, data

Estou precisando pegar o dia que começa e termina cada semana do mês corrente:

> 1 - 2019-10-01 à 2019-10-04
>
> 2 - 2019-10-07 à 2019-10-11

---

```
$today_date = date("Y-m-d");
$currentWeek = ceil((date("d",strtotime($today_date)) 
                   - date("w",strtotime($today_date)) - 1) / 7) + 1;

$i = 1;
while ($i <= $currentWeek) {
    echo "X";
    //$last_week_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last week friday"));
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize formatos relativos https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.formats.relative.php

```
  $dataInicial = new DateTime('first day of this month');
  $dataFinal = new DateTime('last day of this month');

  echo  'Data Inicial: '.$dataInicial->format("d/m/Y").'<br>';
  echo  'Data Final: '.$dataFinal->format("d/m/Y").'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelos seus exemplos, você quer somente os dias de segunda à sexta do mês atual. Sendo assim, você pode tirar proveito dos [formatos relativos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) para iterar pelas datas:

```
$data = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$dow = $data->format('N');
if ($dow == 6 || $dow == 7) {
    // se for sábado ou domingo, ajusta para a próxima segunda-feira
    $data->modify('Monday');
}
$mes = $data->format('m');
$mesmo_mes = TRUE;
while ($mesmo_mes) {
    $inicio = $data->format("Y-m-d");
    $data->modify('Friday');
    if ($mes != $data->format('m')) {
        // foi para o mês seguinte, voltar para o mês atual e ajustar para para o último dia
        $data = new DateTime('last day of this month');
        $mesmo_mes = FALSE;
    }
    echo  "{$inicio} - {$data->format('Y-m-d')} <br>";
    $data->modify('Monday');
    if ($mes != $data->format('m')) {
        break; // se a próxima segunda-feira está no mês seguinte, sai do loop
    }
}
```

Eu começo no primeiro dia do mês e vou até a próxima sexta-feira (usando `modify('Friday')`). Caso a sexta-feira esteja no mês seguinte, eu faço um ajuste para o último dia do mês.

Também trato outros casos, como se o primeiro dia do mês cair em um fim de semana, eu ajusto para a próxima segunda-feira. No meio do loop, se a segunda-feira seguinte estiver no próximo mês (ou seja, o mês pode terminar no sábado ou domingo), eu não preciso imprimir a respectiva semana.

Em seguida imprimo o início e fim de cada semana no formato indicado (ano-mês-dia).

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo do dia, pode ter alguns erros em sua aplicação, por isso é importante verificar em qual semana está se obtendo os dias (isso por causa que alguns lugares a semana começa na segunda, e não no domingo)

```php
    $sunday = new DateTime('2019-10-29');
    $sunday->modify(($sunday->format('w') === '0') ? 'sunday this week' : 'sunday last week');

    $saturday = new DateTime('2019-10-29');
    $saturday->modify(($saturday->format('w') === '6') ? 'now' : 'saturday this week');

    echo 'semana começa em:'. $sunday->format('d/m/y');
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'semana termina em:'. $saturday->format('d/m/y');
```

depois disso é só adicionar isso dentro de um foreach ou algun outro loop com a contagem do mês